# Does index help in Mongo bitwise query

Tags: mongodb

I learnt that bitwise query was introduced to MongoDB since 3.2.

ref:  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/bitsAllSet/#op._S_bitsAllSet

Will these queries be speed up by indexes on numeric fields? If so, how does it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mongodb does not support index for bitwise query now https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-24749;

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)